# How to get groups of relations by the smallest value of a specific property?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core

Question is simple. I have a relation of Model1 to Model2 - the relation between those is ordered by an position-value which is ascending.

if i have for example something like this

```
Model1ToModel2{Model1Id = 1, Model2Id=1 , Position = 1}
Model1ToModel2{Model1Id = 1, Model2Id=2 ,Position = 2}
Model1ToModel2{Model1Id = 2, Model2Id=1 ,Position = 1}
Model1ToModel2{Model1Id = 2, Model2Id=2 ,Position = 2}
```

How can i transform it into something like this?

```
Model1ToModel2{Model1Id = 1, Model2Id=1, Position = 1}
Model1ToModel2{Model1Id = 2, Model2Id=1, Position = 1}
```

Note: Position 1 is not always the beginning, a relation with position 1 could be deleted which leads to Position 2 being the first occurence.

Thanks :)

Edit: So far i have a list of all the relations - but i cant wrap my head around how to seperate groups of Model1 and after seperating them getting the relation with the smallest position.

Comment: Could you plz show what you did so far to achieve the output?

Comment: What i did so far is to go for the Min(p => p.Position), but i cant figur out how to iterate over the different Model1-Objects so i that i get the Relation with the smallest position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
relations.GroupBy(r=>r.Model1Id) // This will group your relations by Model1Id
         //If I understood correctly, you want to keep only the ones with the smallest position
         .Select(group=>group.First(r=>r.Postion == group.Min(item=>item.Position));
```

I did not test that, but provided I understood correctly what do you want, It should work.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution

First I do:
`GroupBy(modelRelation => modelRelation.Model1Id)`

Then I something like this:

```
var newList = new List<T>();
foreach(var group in relations)
{
     var minElement = group.OrderBy(e => e.Position).ToList().FirstOrDefault();
     newList.Add(minElement);
}
```